# How to place a changeable html element on ther same line?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a javascript beginner question. I just want to put some text on the same line (as rendered in html), but where I can change the second element. Something like

```
Function to solve: <div id="eq">equation</div>
```

But in the html page these two expressions are on different lines, i.e. in the browser I see something like

```
Function to solve:
equation
```

but I want to have:

```
Function to solve: equation
```

so I can change the content of the element with id `eq` with some equation (and colors, borders etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `span` instead of `div` and that should solve your issue.

```
Function to solve: <span id="eq">equation</span>
```

Or you can use some css style to inline that item if you want to use the `div`.

Answer (score 1):

div is a block element and the behavior is expected, use `span` rather but if you insist then add the below

```
style="display: inline"
```

```html
Function to solve: <div id="eq" style="display: inline" >equation</div>
```

Comment: No any reason to create a block item, and then make her displaying inline in inline styles. I mean better create a span.

Comment: yup, added that to the answer as well, but if the OP insists on a `div` I've given an alternate solution

Answer (score 1):

Change `<div id="eq">equation</div>` to `<span id="eq">equation</span>`